# Embed video code from third party providers

Tags: 6

I want embed video to my node, module "[Embedded Media Field](http://drupal.org/project/emfield)" do this for some third party providers, but I want embed videos from [Aparat](http://www.aparat.com/) which not supported by emfield. is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the embed code from aparat and it reminded me of Slideshare's code. I tested it by entering its embed code the same way I do with Slideshare (copying the embed code into a **non**-rich text editing window) and it worked.

As with Slideshare, sometimes the video doesn't appear even after loading. The fix if that happens  is to refresh. It will show the second time.